# How to adjust the height of my slider?

Tags: html, css

I have a slider that is too big for me. I want to adjust this big slider. It appears that `height` doesn't fix it.

Preview of slider:
[image]

Code of my CSS, it appears to be in the `sliderSection` part of the styles.css.

```
#sliderSection{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
 /* height: 530px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 77px; 
}
```

EDIT: Here is the HTML code together with the CSS:

```
 <section id="sliderSection">            
    <div class="mainslider_area">
      <!-- Start super slider -->
      <div id="slides">
        <ul class="slides-container">
          <!-- Start single slider-->
          <li>
            <img src="img/slider/2.jpg" alt="img">
            <div class="slider_caption">
              <h2><span>D. Midland</span> Pacific Hotel</h2>
              <p style="color: #000;">Located in the heart of <span>Bauan, Batangas.</span></p>
              <a class="slider_btn" href="#">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </li> 
          <!-- Start single slider-->           
          <li>
            <img src="img/slider/2.jpg" alt="img">
             <div class="slider_caption">
              <h2><span>Online</span> Reservation? <br>We have it covered!</h2>
              <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters.Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search</p>
              <a class="slider_btn" href="#">Read More</a>
            </div>
            </li>
          <!-- Start single slider-->
          <li>
            <img src="img/slider/2.jpg" alt="img">
             <div class="slider_caption">
              <h2><span>Beausiness</span> & Corporate</h2>
              <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters.Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search</p>
              <a class="slider_btn" href="#">Read More</a>
            </div>
           </li>
        </ul>
        <nav class="slides-navigation">
          <a href="#" class="next"></a>
          <a href="#" class="prev"></a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
  </section>
  <!-- End slider section -->

  <!-- Start Service area -->
  <section id="service">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="service_area">
          <div class="service_title">
            <hr>
            <h2>Amenities and Services</h2>
            <p>Experience the hotel that is a place like home.</p>
          </div>
          <ul class="service_nav wow flipInX">
            <li>
              <a class="service_icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a>
              <h2>Online reservation powered</h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
              <a class="read_more" href="#">read more<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
            </li>
           <li>
              <a class="service_icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
              <h2>Affordable Prices!</h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
              <a class="read_more" href="#">read more<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="service_icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-support"></i></a>
              <h2>A comfortable place to stay</h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
              <a class="read_more" href="#">read more<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End Service area -->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add your html code

Comment: Please make sure that you haven't set the slider to `position: relative`

Comment: The `sliderSection` doesn't have that, but it appears other css codes have that. but I'm not quite sure if it relates to the adjustment of the height of the big slider. with the `sliderSection` tag.

Comment: It needs more context to answer the question. Do you have a link to the code in action, either on your site or where you got the snippet from?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have as of now. I'm just working on my local computer.

Comment: you can make  a SO snippet or a jsfiddle

Comment: Agreed you need to provide the complete code example. However, the height in your slider is determined by the images so you need to change the images to change the height of the slider.

Comment: I have uploaded the sample of my website to my free hosting account: http://kensixx.x10host.com/DMidlandBlue/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation for the Outlook theme that looks like the one you're using, have a read: [WPFreeware Outlook theme documentation for Slider setup](https://www.wpfreeware.com/docs/outlook-documentation/#slider-setup)

It recommends you make sure all images are the same. The images are 1920 x 900, I think if you want shorter you decrease the ratio from 2:1 (as is this 1920 x 900 size) to something like 3:2, 1200x400. Adjust size of the image till you like the height.

Comment: I tried another image, but I think it still doesn't fix it. I think what might fix this is a code that auto-resizes the images heights... but I don't exactly what and where to put it..

Comment: Please provide the live url for the theme you're using. Thanks!

Comment: I have uploaded the sample of the website to my free hosting account: kensixx.x10host.com/DMidlandBlue

Comment: Can you choose which slider you want to use for home page? If so, choose one other than SuperSlider which is full screen by default. Otherwise, you need to update the js call in custom.js to add a callback for height other than "window" by default. More here in documentation: https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides

Comment: Hi if my answer worked for your problem, please vote it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hi you can set height to the image of the slider as follow

```
<style>section#sliderSection li img{height:500px;}</style>
```

Comment: I tried putting in the head section of my page, it still doesn't work..